# How to get name of the job owner in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When someone creates a Test job, we should send email only to him, not for all. How can I get a job owner name?

We have teams and when we make a job, the results of it we send to them. But if the name of the job consists "TestJob" we should send only to the creator.

Comment: job owner as in, the one who triggered the job? Possible answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/jenkinsci/comments/8607z3/get_the_username_who_clicked_build_now_in_jenkins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)

It will give you the executing users name and email address.